# Unable to connect GCP SQL Instance from GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a vpc-native cluster and I am trying to connect from a pod inside the cluster to a postgres SQL instance with a private IP.

I am testing using a basic *telnet  5432* command.

The connection works fine when I try it from a GCE instance that is in the same VPC. All connectivity tests in GCP are giving me green light so it seems to be a k8s issue.

Here is my cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters create alex-test \                                                            
    --network=factory-vpc \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --enable-ip-alias \
    --subnetwork=europe-west1-factory-subnet \
    --cluster-ipv4-cidr="/16" \
    --services-ipv4-cidr="/20"
```

Here is how I am testing the connectivity:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox sh
telnet <private ip> 5432
```

Here is my network config in terraform:

```
resource "google_compute_network" "factory" {
  name                    = "factory-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false

  depends_on = [google_project_service.compute]
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "factory_subnet" {
  name                     = "${var.region}-factory-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range            = "10.0.0.0/16"
  region                   = var.region
  network                  = google_compute_network.factory.self_link
  private_ip_google_access = true

  secondary_ip_range {
    ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/16"
    range_name    = "pods"
  }

  secondary_ip_range {
    ip_cidr_range = "10.3.0.0/16"
    range_name    = "services"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "gitlab_google_private_peering" {
  provider      = google-beta
  name          = "gitlab-gcp-private"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  network       = google_compute_network.factory.self_link
  prefix_length = 16
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "gitlab_google_private_peering" {
  provider                = google-beta
  network                 = google_compute_network.factory.self_link
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.gitlab_google_private_peering.name]
}
```

I have already checked the following documentation and articles, but nothing helps:

- [Vpc native cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips)
- [Connecting to SQL from GKE](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine#private-ip)
- [Another issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/992199/cannot-connect-to-cloud-sql-postgres-from-gke-via-private-ip)
- [Another issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/938075/issue-connecting-to-cloud-sql-postgres-using-private-ip-from-gke)

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Can you post the error for your telnet container?

Comment: @GariSingh After a minute or so: "Connection closed by foreign host"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if you are able to reach from a GCE instance in the same VPC to the postgres SQL instance with a private IP but if it didn't work from the pod, I would suggest you to give a look to the [ip masquerade agent](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ip-masquerade-agent). My assumption here is that when you're trying from the pod,  IP masquerading is applying to the packet emitted by said Pod, hence GKE is changin the packet's source address from the Pod IP to the underlying node's IP address so then you're not able to reach your SQL instance because it is in a different range.

If this is the scenario, in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent) you would be able to check how to config/edit it.